# Why is pd.Timestamp converted to np.datetime64 when calling '.values'?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, datetime64

**When accessing the `DataFrame.values`, all `pd.Timestamp` objects are converted to `np.datetime64` objects, why?** An `np.ndarray` containing `pd.Timestamp` objects can exists, therefore I don't understand why would such automatic conversion always happen.

Would you know how to prevent it?

Minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Let's declare an array with a datetime.datetime object
values = [datetime.now()]
print(type(values[0]))
> <class 'datetime.datetime'>

# Clearly, the datetime.datetime objects became pd.Timestamp once moved to a pd.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['A'])
print(type(df.iloc[0][0]))
> <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# Just to be sure, lets iterate over each datetime and manually convert them to pd.Timestamp
df['A'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
print(type(df.iloc[0][0]))
> <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

# df.values (or series.values in this case) returns an np.ndarray
print(type(df.iloc[0].values))
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# When we check what is the type of elements of the '.values' array, 
# it turns out the pd.Timestamp objects got converted to np.datetime64
print(type(df.iloc[0].values[0]))
> <class 'numpy.datetime64'>


# Just to double check, can an np.ndarray contain pd.Timestamps?
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(datetime.now())
timestamps = np.array([timestamp])
print(type(timestamps))
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# Seems like it does. Why the above conversion then?
print(type(timestamps[0]))
> <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

*python : 3.6.7.final.0*

*pandas  : 0.25.3*

*numpy   : 1.16.4*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a workaround - using `.array` instead of `.values` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html))

```py
print(type(df['A'].array[0]))
> <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

This prevents the conversion and gives me access to the objects I wanted to use.

Comment: Thank you so much. I find the `.values` function a bit counter-intuitive: I would expect it to simply access the values in the series and not to do a conversion to the Numpy representation. `.array` is exactly what I was looking for, but again, to me is not an intuitive syntax: I would prefer to be able to access the values as a list; e.g.: `df['A'][0]`.

Comment: For such indexing you can use [`.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html).

Answer (score 5):

The whole idea behind `.values` is to:

> Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame. [[docs]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

I find it logical that a `pd.Timestamp` is then 'downgraded' to a `dtype` that is native to `numpy`. If it wouldn't do this, what is then the purpose of `.values`?

If you do want to keep the `pd.Timestamp` `dtype` I would suggest working with the original `Series` (`df.iloc[0]`). I don't see any other way since [`.values` uses `np.ndarray`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cab3a0ec14a0ebf8d99fb9c2965599ce8c775c9a/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L3832) to convert according to the source on Github.

Comment: It appears using `.to_numpy()` instead, as the docs suggest, would create the possibility to coerce a certain `dtype` but this fails for me ("TypeError: data type "pd.Timestamp" not understood")

Comment: But then why they state `The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype`? If the Series contains only one type, why casting it? I guess they really wanna stress that *Numpy* representation. Could it be that I'm using a wrong function? How can one access the internal data structure of a DataFrame, without doing any casting? Or otherwise, how can one convert a DataFrame into an np.ndarray without casting? That - I believed - was the purpose of `.values`.

Comment: I don't think it is cast to `np.datetime64` because that is the lower-common-denominator dtype, but because `pd.Timestamp` is not part of `numpy`. A vector with `pandas` functionalities is a `Series` and converting it to a `numpy` arrray removes those `pandas` functionalities.